# Unable to create process using '/usr/bin/env

Tags: python, android, kotlin, debugging, error-logging

I am trying to use Pidcat for logging. I downloaded the Pidcat.py and pasted it in the following directory:
**C:\Python\Scripts**
Added this path in the Environment Variables as well. But when I try to log in using the following command:
**pidcat -s deviceId**
I get the following error:
**Unable to create process using '/usr/bin/env -S python -u "C:\Python\Scripts\pidcat.py"  -s deviceId'**

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` can work only on Linux

Comment: This is all that I am getting. There is nothing before this line nor after it. That's why I am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I used CMD to run a python file `getofflinelog.py`.
The command is:

```
python getofflinelog.py -m txt -d camlog -o offline.log
```

I got a similar error `Unable to create process using '/usr/bin/env....`, and I solved it by changing the command to:

```
C:\Users\liutongjun\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe getofflinelog.py -m txt -d camlog -o offline.log
```

I also found that if I added this path to the environment variables, the first short command would work.

I'm not very clear why it works, I do not install Python in this path and there are only a series of exe programs in this folder. Just for reference.